# Python article.text output to output.txt file UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python

I have made this code:

```
from newspaper import Article

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States'
article = Article(url)
article.download()
article.parse()
print(article.text)
```

It correctly prints the wikipedia article to the screen when run, but I want it to save the contents (essentially the screen output) in a .txt file on my computer.

I thought this would be possible by adding:

```
import sys

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    sys.stdout = f
    print(article.text)
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout_
```

However, when I run this, I get an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2032' in position 16074: character maps to <undefined>
```

Why is this error occuring when purely the text data from webpage has been extracted? What can I do to resolve the error?

Thank you

Comment: There's no need to reassign `sys.stdout`. Use `print(article.text, file=f)`